# Kaggle notebook struggles to download RESNET34 FastAI

Tags: python, kaggle, resnet, fast-ai

I'm using kaggle kernel and trying to run the line

`learn = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet34, metrics=error_rate)`

at first it says that it really is downloading the resnet34 trained weights by image net just like so:

`Downloading: "https://download.pytorch.org/models/resnet34-333f7ec4.pth" to /root/.cache/torch/checkpoints/resnet34-333f7ec4.pth`

But after a while it throws an error with heck long of a trace so i'll just put the bottom line which is:

`URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>`

Anyone has any idea as to what is this error and/or how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance! (:

**P.S** I'm following the tutorial right here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfoYk_Z5AkI&t=838s

**Edit**: I've noticed that this error happens only when I try to run this line of code on a gpu kernel and when I run it on non-gpu kernel it downloads perfectly without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and asked about it in the FastAI Discord. It turns out that you have to "enable internet" for your Kernel in Kaggle, so it can be Downloaded.

In your Kaggle notebook, at the right-top you have the icon: `|<` (on the right-side of the blue "Save Version").
Click that icon, and then under "Settings", there is a "Internet" slider. You'll need to verify your account with a phone number.

Answer (score 0):

try using pretrainedmodels

[code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxHRw.jpg)

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate and explain what you did rather than just posting a code?

Comment: yeah.,I used pretrainedmodels package which has more pretrained models than fastai.models then adjusted the architecture and used it in training my fastai model